# Show data in json view after injection in a matDailog (Angular 9+)

Tags: angular, angular-material, json-view, mat-dialog

I need to show data in JSON view inside [MatDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). I am using an API to fetch some data and then injecting it into the dialog box using `data` option of `MatDialog`. Data is being injected successfully and also accessible in the dialog component. I'm using [ngx-json-viewer package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-json-viewer) to display this data in JSON view but it's not working.
Here's how I'm opening the dialog box and passing data into it-

```
const logDetailsDialogRef = this.dialog.open(logDetailsDialog, {
    data: {
        logDetails
    }
});
```

And here is what I am using on my template page-

```
<ngx-json-viewer [json]="data.logDetails"></ngx-json-viewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must inject @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data in your constructor.

```
  constructor(
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dataF,
        private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    
      )
    
     ngOnInit(): void {
    
    
      this.data = this.dataF;
    
    
      }
```

this remains the same:

```
const logDetailsDialogRef = this.dialog.open(logDetailsDialog, {
    data: {
        logDetails
    }
});
```

Comment: already doing that but haven't mentioned the code in question.
`constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data) {}`
My problem is not the data injection. Data is being injected successfully and is accessible in the dialog template (as I mentioned above). I just want to show that data in **json view**